# Discard duplicate records from excel to Mysql in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem:

for example, my excel table looks like this:

```
Reference  |   Amount   |   Qty 
----------------------------------
 541254    |   93       |   0.60

 103485    |   9377     |   0.80 

 021645    |   9375     |   0.80

 021645    |   9375     |   0.80
```

I want to import an excel file into a mysql databases, but some records are duplicated. What i want to do is to check if a record, in a certain field or fields, is duplicated.
If a record is duplicated, I load a single record into the DDBB and ignore the other one.
I have a method that does that check but it gives me a failure og the type:

> "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' "

this is my code but i don`t know what i might have wrong. help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using SpreadsheetLight;     

public static string LoadToMySQL(string file, string table)
            {
                // file = @"C:\Users\Documents\excel_01.xlsx" path to my file
                // table = table of my BBDD
                program myobject = new program(); //Reference to the method "duplicate record"
                string reply = "";
                SLDocument sl = new SLDocument(file);
    
                int i = 2;
             
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
                connection.ConnectionString = configuracion.conexion;
                connection.Open();
    
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sl.GetCellValueAsString(i, 1)))
                {        
                        string Reference = sl.GetCellValueAsString(i,1); 
                        string Amount = sl.GetCellValueAsString(i,2);
    
    
                    // validate code(LINK_REFERENCE) and to know if it exists in the table in order to: discard it or insert it.
                    if (myobject.datosExistentes(reference, amount)) //Reference to the method "duplicate record"
                        {
                            createLog("the reference exists: " + Reference + " with the amount: " + Amount);
                        }
    
                        else
                        {
                            string query = "INSERT INTO "+ table + "(REFERENCE, AMOUNT, QTY)" +
                            "VALUES(@reference, @amount, @qty)";
                            try
                            {
                                MySqlCommand mycmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                                mycmd.Connection = connection;
    
                                mycmd.Parameters.Clear();
                                mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reference", sl.GetCellValueAsString(i, 1));
                                mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", sl.GetCellValueAsString(i, 2));
                                mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", sl.GetCellValueAsString(i, 3));
                                mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                reply = "OK";
                            }
                            catch (MySqlException e)
                            {
                                createLog(e.ToString());
                            }
                    }
                 i++;
                }
                return reply;
            }
    
       private bool duplicateRecords(string reference, string amount)
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
                connection.ConnectionString = configuracion.conexion;
                connection.Open();
    
                string query = "SELECT " + reference + " FROM MY_DDBB WHERE (amount ='" + amount+ "';";
                MySqlCommand mycmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                int num = Convert.ToInt32(mycmd.ExecuteScalar()); //here i get error!!!
    
                if (num > 0)
                {             
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                } 
    
    public static void createLog(string logMessage)
            {
             .....
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a unique key to the field or fields you want to use for duplication detection, then you could simply perform one query doing the job, by leveraging MySQLs `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` function (i.e.):

```csharp
string query = "INSERT INTO "+ table + " (REFERENCE, AMOUNT, QTY) " +
               "VALUES (@reference, @amount, @qty) " +
               "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE QTY=VALUES(QTY);";
```

This will produce an unnecessary un-harming update to the same value, but avoids duplicate inserts all in one command and with no further logic needed in your code.

Just remember to define the unique key in your table schema for the field or fields that you want to consider, so MySQL can detect the duplication.

Comment: This does not help me to solve my problem. My method I think only looks at the first record and should look at all of them and compare if they are the same. I have no unique key or PK in my table. I just import what is in Excel to my DDBB.

Comment: I was assuming, that "reference" is your unique identifier. To see where the error is within your SQL string, you might want to log the generated SQL string from mycmd before executing it and add that to your error description.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **amount** is a numeric column,

```
string query = "SELECT " + reference + " FROM MY_DDBB WHERE (amount ='" + amount+ "';"
```

should be

```
string query = "SELECT " + reference + " FROM MY_DDBB WHERE (amount = " + amount+ ";";
```

Better to use parameters as in the insert statement.